# React native flex item between two views

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to put an item in middle of two views,
it's should look something like this:

[image]

so I know how to flex the orange and blue views, the problem is the green view.

I know i can set his view to absolute and add margin-top of 100 or something like that.

but it will not change relative to the screen width and height.

someone knows how to do it so the green view will change according to the screen width and height?

this is what I got so far:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

export default class MyLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: 300,
        height: 500,
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          flexGrow: 1,
        }} />
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          flexGrow: 3,
        }} />
        <View style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          marginTop: 130,
          position: 'absolute',
        }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen height that way

```
height: Dimensions.get('window').height
```

Of course do not forget to import it

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'
```

hen you can give it a relative distance according to the height
For example

```
height/2
```